# how to compile the sorcecode of the offical ls.c source code?

Tags: compiling, coreutils

I downloaded [the official `ls.c` source code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/ls.c) and tried to compile it with gcc. The problem was that the gcc showed me a lot of errors.

```
$ gcc ls.c -o ls

ls.c:38:20: fatal error: config.h:
```

I did fix a lot of those errors by searching with the find command into my dictonarys

```
$ find /usr/src/ -name "nameofthelibary" 2> /dev/null
```

for some libarys i found the correct path, so for example i could place them into the `#include <config.h> => #include </usr/src/linuxheader.../config.h>`
as i mentioned this method worked for some libarys but not for the header for example `#include "die.h"`

so my question is now: is there any way to compile this ls.c ? cz i want to learn how it works by modifying it

Comment: You should clone the full coreutils, then follow the `README.hacking` file

Comment: ty bro, i didnt know that there is such a file :)

Answer (score 9):

`ls` is part of the coreutils package and as such depends on both other files within coreutils, and the configuration steps. You probably could spend a long time unravelling it from the library but unless you're planning on compiling this a few hundred times a day, I don't think it's worth it.

As pim said in the comments, you can learn about the full build process from [the `README.hacking` file](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/plain/README-hacking) in the root of the git tree. I ran the following without really paying that much heed but this is what worked for me.

```
sudo apt install git build-essential
sudo apt build-dep coreutils

git clone git://git.savannah.gnu.org/coreutils.git
cd coreutils

./bootstrap  # grabs submodules, sets up configuration
./configure  # does actual compiler configuration

make clean  # remove old attempts
make -j8  # compile using 8 threads (you might want to alter this)
```

That will compile everything in the `src` directory and leave the binaries in there. You can run your newly compiled `ls` with `./src/ls`. You can make changes and as long as they're lightweight, you can re-compile them with just the `make` steps.

Comment: also a big thanks for you, i solved it with the README.hacking file
after using ./bootstrap i had to  install autoconf and some other tools to get it started. Its working now.
Ty again :)

Comment: `make -j $(nproc)` is usually a good default - nproc prints number of available logical cpu cores